# Laravel 5.6. SELECT UNION + pagination = object collection

Tags: select, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.6

В контроллере есть 2 запроса с помощью eloquent orm, которые ищут сначало в 1 таблице данные, потом в другой, по 15 шт, и выводят массивы объектов в шаблон.

```
$resultComplex = Complex::where(function ($query) use ($val) {
    /** @var QueryBuilder $query */
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%" . $val . "%");
    $query->orWhere('code', 'like', $val . "%");

})->whereIsActive(true)
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->paginate(15);

$resultAnalyse = Analyse::where(function ($query) use ($val) {
    /** @var QueryBuilder $query */
    $query->where('title', 'like', "%" . $val . "%");
    $query->orWhere('code', 'like', $val . "%");
})->whereIsActive(true)
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли объединить эти запросы, на примере такого запроса:

```
 select * from 
            (select * from complexes union select * from analyses) 
limit 0,15
```

т.е. чтобы запрос сначало проверял данные в таблице complexes, и если там нет 15 записей, то продолжал делать выборку в таблице analyses. И в результате получалась общая выборка из 15 объектов. Именно объектов, а не массивов. Потому что там в объектах имеются связи на другие сущности.

Comment: А если в первой есть 15, то во второй уже не ищем, т.е 15 должно получиться всего?

Comment: да, во второй не ищем, но если мы перейдем на 2 страницу, т.е. LIMIT 15, 30, тогда он должен проверить остались ли в 1 таблице записи, если не остались, тогда выбираем из 2 таблицы